# MSWord Applescript: Cant Insert Table after a Paragraph

Tags: ms-word, applescript

I have a serious issue with trying to add a Paragraph after a table. It seems no matter what command I use the text always appears inside the table even though I have created a new Paragraph and moved the range forward. Any help with this script would be hugely appreciated.

Please see script below:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    set myDocument to make new document
    set documentName to name of myDocument
    activate object document documentName
    set myTitle to create range myDocument start 0 end 0
    set content of myTitle to "Word Export"
    set myTitle to expand myTitle by a sentence item
    select myTitle
    set ascii name of font object of text object of selection to "calibri"
    set other name of font object of text object of selection to "calibri"
    set bold of text object of selection to true
    set font size of font object of text object of selection to 16
    set alignment of paragraph format of text object of selection to align paragraph center
    collapse range text object of selection direction collapse end
    insert paragraph at text object of selection
    insert paragraph at text object of selection
    insert text "Category - All" at text object of paragraph 2 of myDocument
    set myCategory to text object of paragraph 2 of active document
    set myCategory to collapse range myCategory direction collapse end
    set bold of myCategory to true
    set font size of font object of text object of paragraph 2 of myDocument to 14
    set alignment of paragraph format of myCategory to align paragraph center
    collapse range text object of selection direction collapse end
    insert paragraph at text object of selection
    insert paragraph at text object of selection
    insert text "Testing 1" at text object of paragraph 4 of myDocument
    set currentParagraph to text object of paragraph 4 of active document
    set bold of currentParagraph to false
    set bold of text object of selection to false
    set font size of font object of text object of paragraph 4 of myDocument to 12
    set alignment of paragraph format of currentParagraph to align paragraph left
    set currentParagraph to collapse range currentParagraph direction collapse end
    collapse range text object of selection direction collapse end
    -- Up to Paragraph 6 
    insert paragraph at text object of selection
    insert paragraph at text object of selection
    set oDoc to active document
    set oTable to make new table at oDoc with properties {text object:(paragraph 6), number of rows:3, number of columns:4}
    collapse range text object of selection direction collapse end
    set myRange to text object of selection
    set myRange to move end of range myRange by a table

    insert paragraph at text object of selection
    insert paragraph at text object of selection
    insert text "Testing 2" at text object of paragraph 8 of myDocument
    set currentParagraph to text object of paragraph 8 of active document
    set bold of currentParagraph to false
    set bold of text object of selection to false
    set font size of font object of text object of paragraph 8 of myDocument to 12
    set alignment of paragraph format of currentParagraph to align paragraph left
    set currentParagraph to collapse range currentParagraph direction collapse end
    collapse range text object of selection direction collapse end
    -- Up to Paragraph 10 
    insert paragraph at text object of selection
    insert paragraph at text object of selection
    set oDoc to active document
    set oTable to make new table at oDoc with properties {text object:(paragraph 10), number of rows:3, number of columns:4}
    collapse range text object of selection direction collapse end
    activate
```

end tell

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are attempting. I'm not particularly familiar with the Word Applescript stuff myself, so there may be far better ways to do this. As a matter of habit I try to avoid using selections, so the key thing is to be able to set the range to the end of the document.

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    set myDocument to make new document
    set documentName to name of myDocument
    activate object document documentName

    set theRange to create range myDocument start 0 end 0
    set content of theRange to "Word Export"
    set theRange to expand theRange by a paragraph item
    set ascii name of font object of theRange to "calibri"
    set other name of font object of theRange to "calibri"
    set bold of theRange to true
    set font size of font object of theRange to 16
    set alignment of paragraph format of theRange to align paragraph center

    set theRange to my appendParagraphs(myDocument, 1)
    insert text "Category - All" at theRange
    set theRange to expand theRange by a paragraph item
    set bold of theRange to true
    set font size of font object of theRange to 14
    set alignment of paragraph format of theRange to align paragraph center

    set theRange to my appendParagraphs(myDocument, 2)
    insert text "Testing 1" at theRange
    set theRange to expand theRange by a paragraph item
    set bold of theRange to false
    set font size of font object of theRange to 12
    set alignment of paragraph format of theRange to align paragraph left

    -- Up to Paragraph 6 
    set theRange to my appendParagraphs(myDocument, 3)
    make new table at theRange with properties {number of rows:3, number of columns:4}
    set theRange to move end of range theRange by a table

    set theRange to my appendParagraphs(myDocument, 1)
    insert text "Testing 2" at theRange
    set theRange to expand theRange by a paragraph item
    set bold of theRange to false
    set font size of font object of theRange to 12
    set alignment of paragraph format of theRange to align paragraph left

    -- Up to Paragraph 10 
    set theRange to my appendParagraphs(myDocument, 3)
    make new table at theRange with properties {number of rows:3, number of columns:4}
    set theRange to move end of range theRange by a table
    --activate
end tell

to endOfDoc(aDocument)
    tell application "Microsoft Word" to tell aDocument to return (create range aDocument start (end of content of text object of aDocument) - 1 end (end of content of text object of aDocument) - 1)
end endOfDoc

to appendParagraphs(aDocument, paraCount)
    tell application "Microsoft Word" to tell aDocument
        repeat paraCount times
            insert paragraph at my endOfDoc(aDocument)
        end repeat
        return my endOfDoc(aDocument)
    end tell
end appendParagraphs
```